# Populate field use as a column key in exceljs

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I am using exceljs to prepare an Excel file. This works fine when the first-level properties of a model are used as column keys. But when the second-level property of a Model is used as a column key, the column appears blank when the excel file gets downloaded.

```
worksheet.columns = [
      { header: "ID", key: "_id", width: 30 },   // work
      { header: "Survey Name", key: "name", width: 30 }, // work
      { header: "Status", key: "status", width: 15 }, // work
      { header: "Survey Type", key: "survey_type.name", width: 50 } // not work
]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I could not find any solution within exceljs. First create a copy of the array such that I bring the required sub-properties as the first-level property, and then use the new array to generate an excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
worksheet.columns = [
    { header: "ID", key: "_id", width: 30 },
    { header: "Survey Name", key: "name", width: 30 },
    { header: "Status", key: "status", width: 15 },
    {
        header: "Survey Type",
        key: "survey_type_name",
        width: 50,
        // Use a custom function to extract the nested property
        // survey_type.name from your data.
        outlineLevel: 1, // Optional property to create an outline level.
        cell: {
            get(value) {
                return value && value.survey_type && value.survey_type.name;
            },
        },
    },
];
```